# center nav breadcrumb ordered list using bootstrap css

Tags: css, center, nav, breadcrumbs

I've been googling and looking at the suggested links before posting the question, but I haven't gotten anything to work.

I have an existing nav menu that I want to center on the page. I am using bootstrap css. I've tried changing the .nav definitions, the ol's, and the breadcrumbs....but they have had no effect.  I can get the nav to center if I use a standalone css, but not by trying to incorporate the changes into the pre-made bootsrtrap file.

HTML

```
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/csstest.css">
</head>

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Home</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Submissions</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Reports</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Database</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Register</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Log Out</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Standalone CSS

```
.breadcrumb{
    padding:8px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    list-style:none;
    background-color:#f5f5f5;
    border-radius:4px
}
.breadcrumb>li{
    display:inline-block
}
.breadcrumb>li+li:before{
    padding:0 5px;
    color:#ccc;
    content:"/\00a0"
}
.breadcrumb>.active{
    color:#777
}
.breadcrumb li a {
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Boostrap CSS

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

(I've linked the CSS since it is too much to put here. But I've created a duplicate on my server that I can edit and use.)

Answer (score 2):

If I got the question right, you should remove your css and just apply class: 'text-center' on the nav element.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jznms2?embed=1&file=index.html

Comment: I'll request that to be tried. (I don't have modify permissions on that file at the moment, just the css.)

Comment: For the record though, this works and is an easy solution. (it does the trick on my test html. I was just trying to figure out why the css wouldn't behave when using the bootstrap css.)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for.

```css
.breadcrumb {
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block !important;
}

.breadcrumb>li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.breadcrumb>li+li:before {
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #ccc;
  content: "/\00a0";
}

.breadcrumb>.active {
  color: #777;
}

.breadcrumb li a {
  color: #0275d8;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.breadcrumb li a:hover {
  color: #01447e;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Home</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Submissions</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Reports</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Database</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Register</li>
    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Log Out</li>
  </ol>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Chris_00 For some reason though when you replace the .breadcrumb pieces in the bootstrap css with these, some other definition overrides them to be left aligned, and I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: Probably something in your css file.